# Is there any reason to use this custom read_char function instead of the builtin read command?

Tags: shell-script, read

I'm not good at bash and Linux. I'm reading a script and I found the following function.

```
get_char()
{
    SAVEDSTTY=`stty -g`
    stty -echo
    stty cbreak
    dd if=/dev/tty bs=1 count=1 2> /dev/null
    stty -raw
    stty echo
    stty $SAVEDSTTY
}
```

Basically, it is used to implement *Press any key to continue* feature like this.

```
echo "Press any key to continue!"
char=`get_char`
```

I know you can use the builtin `read` command to implement this. For example:

```
read -rsn1 -p "Press any key to continue"
```

Is there any reason to use this function instead of the builtin `read` command?

Comment: That syntax is specific to the `bash` shell and can't be used in any other shell. The -r, -s, -n are copied from ksh93 (zsh had `-k` instead of `-n` long before ksh93 or bash though), `-p` to issue a prompt is bash specific.  ksh/zsh's syntax is `read 'varname?Prompt: '`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas So are you saying the function is more portable?

Comment: fwiw, you can simplify it: `get_char(){ _g=$(stty -g); stty raw -echo; dd count=1 2>/dev/null; stty "$_g"; }`. If you want it to always read the key from the tty, use it as `get_char </dev/tty` -- both `stty` and `dd` will use the stdin by default.

Comment: @philippe it all depends on what you want to do: imho, it's an __improvement__ that `k=$(get_char)` will set `k` to the entire `^[OP` escape when you press `F1` instead of eating up the `^[` and leaving the `OP` to be read afterwards, as it would happen with `bs=1` ;-)

Comment: ... or with `read -rsn1` (but `read` at least will cope with multibyte characters, which `dd bs=1` of course won't).

Comment: yes, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get_char` function from the question has problems wrt keys which generate multibyte characters and with the fact that `stty` acts on the stdin but `dd` reads from `/dev/tty`[1], so I'll use a "fixed" and simplified version of it to do the comparison:

```
get_char(){
  _g=$(stty -g); stty raw -echo; dd count=1 2>/dev/null; stty "$_g"
}
```

Some differences between `k=$(get_char)` and `read -rsn1 k` are:

1. the former is portable; it works the same in `dash`, `bash`, `zsh`, etc. `read -rsn1` only works in `bash` and `ksh`.
2. when a key like `F1` is pressed, `k=$(get_char)` will set `k` to the entire escape generated by the `F1` key (`^[OP`) instead of eating up the leading `^[` (Esc) and leaving the `OP` for later. The same thing applies to any key which generates multiple characters.
3. `Ctrl-C` (`VINTR`), `Ctrl-Q` (`VQUIT`) or `Ctrl-Z` (`VSUSP`) will cause `k=$(get_char)` to set `k` to the raw control character (`\x03`, `\x11` or `\x1a`), while it will interrupt or suspend the script when the `read -rsn1` is used [2].

---

[1] If it should read from the controlling tty, it's simple to use it as `k=$(get_char </dev/tty)`

[2] `read -rsn1` will fail to restore the tty settings if the script was suspended with `Ctrl-Z` and then resumed with `fg`.

Example when used from a shell with a line-editor -- which is itself messing with the tty settings:

```
$ bash -c 'read -rsn1 foo; echo "{$foo}"'
<Ctrl-Z>
[4]+  Stopped                 bash -c 'read -rsn1 foo; echo "{$foo}"'
$ fg
bash -c 'read -rsn1 foo; echo "{$foo}"'
f<Enter>
{f}
$
$ bash -c 'read -rsn1 foo; echo "{$foo}"'
<Ctrl-Z>
[4]+  Stopped                 bash -c 'read -rsn1 foo; echo "{$foo}"'
$ fg
bash -c 'read -rsn1 foo; echo "{$foo}"'
foo<Enter>
{f}
$ oo
bash: oo: command not found
```

Or when used from a shell which does not mess with the tty settings (eg. `dash`):

```
$ bash -c 'read -rsn1 foo; echo "{$foo}"'
<Ctrl-Z>
[1] + Stopped                    bash -c "read -rsn1 foo; echo \"{\$foo}\""
$ <Blindly type f, g, Enter>bash -c "read -rsn1 foo; echo \"{\$foo}\""
{e}
$
```